# In "Was isst du am liebsten", what's the explanation of "du am liebsten", instead of "deine am liebsten"?

Tags: pronoun, possessive-pronoun, nominative

I've just started to learn German, and I encountered this sentence:

> Was isst **du am liebsten**?

The translation, according to he video that I'm learning from, is

> What's your favourite food?

But as far as I know *du* is a personal nominative pronoun for the 2<sup>nd</sup> person; and based on my limited and superficial knowledge, I expected to see *deine*, the possessive pronoun form for the 2<sup>nd</sup> person, here. Is there an explanation for this?

On asking similar questions about the interests of others, how should I know when I should use *du* or *deine*?

Is it possible to form a question/sentence in German, without having something represented as nominative case in it?

Comment: Natural translations between languages often aren't literal - though sometimes it can be very helpful, especially for beginners, to have *literal* translations. To literally ask "What is your favorite food?" you could say "Was ist dein Lieblingsessen?". "Was isst du am liebsten?" means "What do you eat" am liebsten (I don't know a good literal translation for "am liebsten", because I'd generally switch to a translation that says "What is your favorite...". It's an adverb for doing a thing while liking it the most). Make sure not to confuse "ist" and "isst" here.

Comment: Was isst du **am lieben** is simply wrong, it must be **am liebsten**.

Comment: "I expected to see deine, the possessive pronoun" Why? There is no such relationship. Compare it with "Was ist deine Lieblingsspeise?", where "deine" is indeed possessive.

Comment: " What do you like to eat the most?" -> No possessive form, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A  more literal translation would be "what do you like to eat the most?". Also, what Nathan says (his comment should be an answer).

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Feel free to include Nathan's comment into your answer, that is encouraged. You still can give him credit for it. Your answer is your choice and everybody commenting should know that others can make an answer of that.

Comment: It's best, not most, isn't it?

Comment: @Iris [Both are possible](https://jakubmarian.com/like-more-vs-like-better-like-the-most-vs-like-most-like-the-best-vs-like-best/)

Comment: @infinitezero in the example of "like" both sounds good to me, but with "eat" I am not sure.

Comment: @Iris Read again, it's literally with "like" :)

Comment: I'd say the closest literal translation is "What do you eat most preferably"?